# UVC Camera no preview is showing when closing activity and reopening it

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, uvc

I want to use UVC camera in my android application. For this i m using this library
https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera

It works the first time the activity is opened,camera preview show properly. When close the activity and come back again to that activity camera preview not showing.Unless i restart my camera or remove app from recent apps.Any body have any idea, how to fix this?
Thanks in Advance.